# decoding message using c

Tags: c, cryptography

I was solving a codewars problem called "decoding a message" using C.

My code passed the sample tests but can't pass the random tests as it adds random chars after the required chars like in the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj03U.png)

What's the problem here?

problem's link : [https://www.codewars.com/kata/565b9d6f8139573819000056]

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *decode (const char *encoded, char *decoded)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(encoded); i++)
  {
    if (isalpha(encoded[i]))
    {
      if (encoded[i] <= 109)
      {
          decoded[i] = encoded[i] + 25 - ((encoded[i] - 'a')*2);  
      }
      else if (encoded[i] >= 110)
      {
          decoded[i] = encoded[i] - 25 + (('z' - encoded[i])*2);
      } 
    }
    else
    {
      decoded[i] = encoded[i];
    }
  }
    return decoded; // return it
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the (required) `nul` terminator to your output string.

Comment: Does your output string have room for the terminating '\0' that you don't seem to append to the output string?

Comment: Ahmed Nader, Best to post text here rather than as a pic elsewhere.

Comment: Especially for the C-language  it will always make sense to also post how the variables have been declared / allocated / initialized. If you put in a string that is one larger than `strlen` and fill it with zero then the error would not have occured, i.e. we do not have enough code to replicate the issue reliably. Similarly, we don't know what the "random tests" look like; if you have code for that then it would make sense to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the symptom described by the OP *suggests* the receiving buffer is not terminated properly to make a C string.

Further, one should avoid using "magic numbers" like 109 and 110 in code... What do those numbers mean?? They certainly won't work if the constraint of being "all lowercase" is lifted. Would one then copy/paste/adapt many lines of code merely to deal with both upper and lower case alphabets?

Below is LESS code that not only deals with the OP problem (unterminated string) but also deals with both upper and lower case letters (recognising that 'case' would weaken any encryption. Included here to demonstrate technique, only.)

Have fun with these learning challenges.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *decode( const char *s, char *d ) {
    for( size_t i = 0; ( d[i] = s[i] ) != '\0'; i++ ) { // copy every byte
        if( isalpha( d[i] ) ) { // transform needed ?
            char c = islower( d[i] ) ? 'a' : 'A'; // basis to transpose ASCII char to 0-25
            d[i] = (char)( c + ( 25 - ( d[i] - c ) ) ); // 0->25 ==> 25->0
        }
    }
    return d; // return it
}

int main() {
    char *hidden = "R slkv MLYLWB wvxlwvh gsrh nvhhztv";
    char buf[ 128 ];

    printf( "%s\n%s\n", hidden, decode( hidden, buf ) );
    return 0;
}
```

```
R slkv MLYLWB wvxlwvh gsrh nvhhztv
I hope NOBODY decodes this message
```

If any of this is unclear, please post a question below...

Comment: I added \0 terminator as said in comments and it worked. I didn't try to work on capital case as it is not required in the problem. I found your code much better and learnt a lot from it but I didn't think about it so I submittd my code even if it's not the best

Comment: @AhmedNader Good that you solved your problem, and especially good that you submitted your own code. My hope writing this answer was to convey some _techniques_ for writing less code to achieve the objective. 'C' is fantastic for being able to _compound_ several related operations into a single statement. Glad to help! Best wishes going forward... (Free advice: study code written by others whenever you can. It's that, "Oh, THAT's how it's done!" experience... `:-)`